# Getting an error when using joins in query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `employee_activities` a
LEFT JOIN `activity` b ON a.activity_code = b.code
LEFT JOIN `employees` c ON a.employee_code = c.code
WHERE b.type = "Design"
AND c.code NOT IN(
    SELECT * FROM `employee_activities` a
        LEFT JOIN `activity` b ON a.activity_code = b.code
        LEFT JOIN `employees` c ON a.employee_code = c.code
        WHERE b.type = "Testing"
)
GROUP BY c.code
```

I get this error:

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I'm tying to get all employees that have at least one activity of type "Design" and None activity of type "Testing".

I have a query that works but I would like it to work with joins.

This works:

```
SELECT c.name FROM `employee_activities` a, `activity` b, `employees` c
WHERE a.activity_code = b.code
AND a.employee_code = c.code
AND b.type = "Design"

AND c.code NOT IN(
    SELECT c.code FROM `employee_activities` a, `activity` b, `employees` c
        WHERE a.activity_code = b.code
        AND a.employee_code = c.code
        AND b.type = "Testing"
)
GROUP BY c.code
```

What did I do wrong on the sql with joins?

Comment: You can't do `SELECT *` in the subquery like that; the `c.code NOT IN` portion is looking for a single cloumn to be returned.

Comment: It sounds like this is solved, but if you're still consider updating your question with a sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the not in sub query - it should contain only one column - for example

```
SELECT * FROM `employee_activities` a
LEFT JOIN `activity` b ON a.activity_code = b.code
LEFT JOIN `employees` c ON a.employee_code = c.code
WHERE b.type = "Design"
AND c.code NOT IN(
    SELECT b.employee_code FROM `employee_activities` a
        LEFT JOIN `activity` b ON a.activity_code = b.code
        LEFT JOIN `employees` c ON a.employee_code = c.code
        WHERE b.type = "Testing"
)
GROUP BY c.code
```

Comment: ooops. yeah my bad. Didn't see that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your query

```
AND c.code NOT IN(
   SELECT * FROM `employee_activities` a
...
```

tries to compare c.code to *all columns in the subquery*. What you want is probably;

```
AND c.code NOT IN(
    SELECT c.code FROM `employee_activities` a
```

Also, you have a problem in your `LEFT JOIN`;

```
LEFT JOIN `activity` b ON a.activity_code = b.code
...
WHERE b.type = "Design"
```

When you compare a column that is left joined in into a `WHERE` clause, it basically turns the whole join into an `INNER JOIN`. Since your original query seems to use an inner join, that should be ok, but you may as well change it to;

```
SELECT * FROM `employee_activities` a
JOIN `activity` b ON a.activity_code = b.code AND b.type='Design'
LEFT JOIN `employees` c ON a.employee_code = c.code
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this part:

```
AND c.code NOT IN(
SELECT * FROM
```

You can't have an * here as its looking to see if c.code is in the list of field values returned and must specify just a single field in the select.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this section:

```
AND c.code NOT IN( 
    SELECT * FROM `employee_activities` a
```

You can't `SELECT *` in that nested query. You need to select exactly one column that will be compared to the `c.code`. You need this instead:

```
AND c.code NOT IN( 
    SELECT c.code FROM `employee_activities` a
```

Answer (score 2):

DO this:

```
SELECT * FROM `employee_activities` a
LEFT JOIN `activity` b ON a.activity_code = b.code
LEFT JOIN `employees` c ON a.employee_code = c.code
WHERE b.type = "Design"
AND c.code NOT IN(
    SELECT c.code FROM `employee_activities` a
        LEFT JOIN `activity` b ON a.activity_code = b.code
        LEFT JOIN `employees` c ON a.employee_code = c.code
        WHERE b.type = "Testing"
)
GROUP BY c.code
```

As here you should compare the data with code column and * will fetch all the records.